# Exclude type checking on certain files

Tags: typescript, css-modules

I have some `styles.istyl` files compiled with a combination of css-modules and stylus with webpack. TypeScript can't recognize it without a `d.ts` file, and emits a `file is not a module` error.

Meanwhile, I'm creating a `.d.ts` file for each such file like so:

```
declare var whatever: any;
export default whatever;
```

to silence the error, but that is tedious (we have dozens of such files).

Is it possible to tell TypeScript to disable checking for whether a file is a module if it matches `*.istyl` (or any other arbitrary pattern)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following code as a global declaration (ie. in a file without `export` and `import`):

```
// global-stylus.d.ts
declare module "*.istyl" {
    const content: string;
    export default content;
}
```

Needs [TypeScript 2.0 or above](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html).

Comment: Hey, could you include how to use this code in your project? (i.e. put in a `.d.ts` file and reference from `tsconfig.json`). A relevant link would be great too.